# Encapsulate node.js code in a function

Tags: node.js, function

So far I have the below code which I need to get the id from a JSON object:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
//var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//var moment = require("moment");

var options =  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "hostname" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "port" : "18080",
    "path" : "/api/v1/applications/"
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

        var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {
            if (body[key].name.indexOf("TestName") > -1) {
                return body[key].name;
            }
        }).reduce(function(obj, key){
            obj = body[key].id;
            return obj;
        }, {});;
        //console.log("Name: ", arrFound);
        console.log("ID: ", arrFound);
    });
});

req.end();
```

I know it's reading the id as I currently write it out to the console(console.log("ID: ", arrFound);).

What I would like to do is have this available for use in other parts of my program. I assume I need to do something like encapsulate it in a function that I can call but node.js is new to me and I'm not entirely sure how/what to do.

Can anybody advise how to do this or point me to some resource that might help?

Comment: What code is it you want to reuse, this entire block or just the JSON parsing / filtering?

Comment: I just want to be able to get the id any time I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should research the module pattern and exports.  You are right, the basic idea is to export your code as a function. Based on how you've approached this, it should take a callback function.  I've made a naive attempt with what you have.

Notice I pass a null as the first argument to the callback function. It is conventional when using callbacks in node to use the first argument for errors. You probably need some error handling.

Having said that, you night look into some libraries like requests, or the ES6 fetch function. These will allow you to organize your code more neatly. You'll probably wind up using promises instead of callbacks.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
//var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//var moment = require("moment");

var options =  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "hostname" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "port" : "18080",
    "path" : "/api/v1/applications/"
};
exports.getId = function(callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

        var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {
            if (body[key].name.indexOf("TestName") > -1) {
                return body[key].name;
            }
        }).reduce(function(obj, key){
            obj = body[key].id;
            return obj;
        }, {});;
        //console.log("Name: ", arrFound);
        callback(null, arrFound));
    });
});

    req.end();
}
```

You call it like this:

```
exports.getId(function(err, id){
    console.log(id)
})
```

Comment: Callbacks are old school, have `getId` return a `Promise` instead so the calling code can make use of `async` / `await`.

Comment: I was doing the minimum with the code at have! If the asker looks into fetch they will be led to a promise based solution!

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into these. I think I have a bit of reading to do.

I assumed I could run something like console.log(exports.getId()); but that throws "TypeError: callback is not a function:" am I missing something?

Comment: Having looked at thisi a little, am I correct in thinking I may be close with console.log(exports.getId()); but that I must pass some value. If so I'm not sure what that might be.

Comment: See the change.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks for all the help. I've a lot of learning to do!

Comment: Indeed you do. There are plenty of resources on the Internet to learn this stuff.